# Rendering 3d objects behind 2d Objects unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, shader

I am making a an isometric game with a combination of 2d and 3d elements. I wish to know how to make my player and enemy sprites (all made up of 2d elemnts) not render behind or inside my 3d elements.

[image]

So I have tried messing about with renderQueue and setting the renderqueue of the materials these rocks and such have to a high value to have them drawn behind the 2d elements.

However through my searching I have found out that I actually need to be setting the ztest of the objects to correct this. This confused me a bit and I am unsure how to do it as I have not really used shaders that much. I could not find any decent references that explain exactly how to go about this just stuff written that assumes prior knowledge like [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1130288/materialrenderqueue-4000-has-no-effect.html). I tried downloading the unity shaders and and opened the default sprite one but I was unsure where to change the ztest or tagging to solve this.

here is the standard sprite shader from unity:

```
// Unity built-in shader source. Copyright (c) 2016 Unity Technologies. MIT license (see license.txt)

#ifndef UNITY_SPRITES_INCLUDED
#define UNITY_SPRITES_INCLUDED

#include "UnityCG.cginc"

#ifdef UNITY_INSTANCING_ENABLED

UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_START(PerDrawSprite)
    // SpriteRenderer.Color while Non-Batched/Instanced.
    UNITY_DEFINE_INSTANCED_PROP(fixed4, unity_SpriteRendererColorArray)
    // this could be smaller but that's how bit each entry is regardless of type
    UNITY_DEFINE_INSTANCED_PROP(fixed2, unity_SpriteFlipArray)
UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_END(PerDrawSprite)

#define _RendererColor  UNITY_ACCESS_INSTANCED_PROP(PerDrawSprite, unity_SpriteRendererColorArray)
#define _Flip           UNITY_ACCESS_INSTANCED_PROP(PerDrawSprite,    unity_SpriteFlipArray)

#endif // instancing

CBUFFER_START(UnityPerDrawSprite)
#ifndef UNITY_INSTANCING_ENABLED
fixed4 _RendererColor;
fixed2 _Flip;
#endif
float _EnableExternalAlpha;
CBUFFER_END

// Material Color.
fixed4 _Color;

struct appdata_t
{
float4 vertex   : POSITION;
float4 color    : COLOR;
float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID
};

struct v2f
{
float4 vertex   : SV_POSITION;
fixed4 color    : COLOR;
float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
UNITY_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO
};

inline float4 UnityFlipSprite(in float3 pos, in fixed2 flip)
{
return float4(pos.xy * flip, pos.z, 1.0);
}

v2f SpriteVert(appdata_t IN)
{
v2f OUT;

UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID (IN);
UNITY_INITIALIZE_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO(OUT);

OUT.vertex = UnityFlipSprite(IN.vertex, _Flip);
OUT.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(OUT.vertex);
OUT.texcoord = IN.texcoord;
OUT.color = IN.color * _Color * _RendererColor;

#ifdef PIXELSNAP_ON
OUT.vertex = UnityPixelSnap (OUT.vertex);
#endif

return OUT;
}

sampler2D _MainTex;
sampler2D _AlphaTex;

fixed4 SampleSpriteTexture (float2 uv)
{
fixed4 color = tex2D (_MainTex, uv);

#if ETC1_EXTERNAL_ALPHA
fixed4 alpha = tex2D (_AlphaTex, uv);
color.a = lerp (color.a, alpha.r, _EnableExternalAlpha);
#endif

  return color;
}

fixed4 SpriteFrag(v2f IN) : SV_Target
{
   fixed4 c = SampleSpriteTexture (IN.texcoord) * IN.color;
   c.rgb *= c.a;
   return c;
 }

#endif // UNITY_SPRITES_INCLUDED
```

### Update 1

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to position your 2D elements in 3D space just like your 3D elements, with their transform position in front/behind whatever they need to be in front of / behind?

Comment: In my case its not a good idea. because my camera is isometric so it looks down at the world at a 41 degree angle. Placing 2d elements "infront" of 3 elements means they get placed at weird angles which makes the aiming system and position of the 2d elemnts all skewed and really becomes messy to work with. Im quite sure the correct way to do this is to be able to tell certain 3D elements that they should simply be rendered behind the 2D elements. I just dont know how to write a shader that does this. UPDATE 1 illustrates how it looks when in-game. Sprite renders infront of tile but not rock.

Comment: Could you use another camera? If you could you can set another camera culling mask and depth.That could make something in the layer will show front.

Comment: shader can do this,but i think use another camera would be easy to impl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, I think you can try using an extra camera.

Correctly set the two cameras's **culling mask** and **depth** and **clear flags**.

The depth of the extra camera should be **higher** and the clearflag should be set to **depth only** and culling mask only set the layer you want render in front.

And your original camera culling mask should delete the layer render in extra camera.

You can make objects of a particular layer render in front.

Yesterday Svp tell me that he want fine-grained control drawing-order of 2d and 3d objects.My old answer can not does this well.So after research, there are three solutions.

**UPDATE:**

1. Treat 2d object as 3d. Use z-pos to sort all objects. Keep few 3d object z-pos always less than or greater than player z-pos (The offset of z-pos of 3d object and player need greater than fixed value that make the entire 3d object behind the player.).The fixed value could select 3d object bounds max.
2. Treat 3d object as 2d. **3d object mesh render use 2d sprite-default shader**.
   Use 2d sorting layer and order in layer control 3d object render.But we need **custom mesh render inspector** use follow code copy from [here by uvivagabond](https://forum.unity.com/threads/drawing-order-of-meshes-and-sprites.212006/).

   ```
   using System;
   using UnityEngine;
   using UnityEditor;
   using UnityEditorInternal;
   using System.Reflection;
   using UnityEngine.Rendering;
   [CanEditMultipleObjects ()]
   [CustomEditor (typeof(MeshRenderer))]
   public class MeshRendererSortingLayersEditor : Editor
   {

       public override void OnInspectorGUI ()
       {

           #region Get Serialized Property
           SerializedProperty sortingLayerID = serializedObject.FindProperty (propertyPath: "m_SortingLayerID");
           SerializedProperty sortingOrder = serializedObject.FindProperty ("m_SortingOrder");

           SerializedProperty castShadows = serializedObject.FindProperty ("m_CastShadows");
           SerializedProperty receiveShadows = serializedObject.FindProperty ("m_ReceiveShadows");
           SerializedProperty motionVectors = serializedObject.FindProperty ("m_MotionVectors");
           SerializedProperty materials = serializedObject.FindProperty ("m_Materials");
           SerializedProperty lightProbes = serializedObject.FindProperty ("m_LightProbeUsage");
           SerializedProperty reflectionProbes = serializedObject.FindProperty ("m_ReflectionProbeUsage");
           SerializedProperty anchorProbes = serializedObject.FindProperty ("m_ProbeAnchor");
           #endregion

           #region Draw Properties
           AddPropertyField (castShadows);
           AddPropertyField (receiveShadows);
           AddPropertyField (motionVectors);
           AddPropertyField (materials);
           AddPopup (ref lightProbes, "Light Probes", typeof(LightProbeUsage));
           AddPopup (ref reflectionProbes, "Reflection Probes", typeof(ReflectionProbeUsage));
           AddPropertyField (anchorProbes, "Anchor Override");
           #endregion


           GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle (GUI.skin.label);
           style.richText = true;
           EditorGUILayout.Space ();
           EditorGUILayout.LabelField ("<b><color=#EE4035FF>SortingLayers Options:</color></b>", style);
           #region SortingLayer
           Rect firstHoriz = EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal ();
           EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck ();
           //    EditorGUI.PropertyField (mat, new GUIContent ("Materials"));
           EditorGUI.BeginProperty (firstHoriz, GUIContent.none, sortingLayerID);
           string[] layerNames = GetSortingLayerNames ();
           int[] layerID = GetSortingLayerUniqueIDs ();
           int selected = -1;
           int sID = sortingLayerID.intValue;
           for (int i = 0; i < layerID.Length; i++)
               if (sID == layerID [i])
                   selected = i;
           if (selected == -1)
               for (int i = 0; i < layerID.Length; i++)
                   if (layerID [i] == 0)
                       selected = i;
           selected = EditorGUILayout.Popup ("Sorting Layer", selected, layerNames);

           sortingLayerID.intValue = layerID [selected];
           EditorGUI.EndProperty ();
           EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal ();
           #endregion

           #region OrderInLayer
           EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal ();
           EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck ();
           EditorGUILayout.PropertyField (sortingOrder, new GUIContent ("Order in Layer"));
           EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal ();
           serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties ();
           #endregion


       }

       void AddPropertyField (SerializedProperty ourSerializedProperty)
       {
           Rect ourRect = EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal ();
           EditorGUI.BeginProperty (ourRect, GUIContent.none, ourSerializedProperty);
           EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck ();

           EditorGUILayout.PropertyField (property: ourSerializedProperty, includeChildren: true); //I set includeChildren:true to display material children

           EditorGUI.EndProperty ();
           EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal ();
       }

       void AddPropertyField (SerializedProperty ourSerializedProperty, string name)
       {
           Rect ourRect = EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal ();
           EditorGUI.BeginProperty (ourRect, GUIContent.none, ourSerializedProperty);
           EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck ();

           EditorGUILayout.PropertyField (ourSerializedProperty, new GUIContent (name), true);

           EditorGUI.EndProperty ();
           EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal ();
       }

       void AddPopup (ref SerializedProperty ourSerializedProperty, string nameOfLabel, Type typeOfEnum)
       {
           Rect ourRect = EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal ();
           EditorGUI.BeginProperty (ourRect, GUIContent.none, ourSerializedProperty);
           EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck ();

           int actualSelected = 1;  
           int selectionFromInspector = ourSerializedProperty.intValue;
           string[] enumNamesList = System.Enum.GetNames (typeOfEnum);
           actualSelected = EditorGUILayout.Popup (nameOfLabel, selectionFromInspector, enumNamesList);
           ourSerializedProperty.intValue = actualSelected;

           EditorGUI.EndProperty ();
           EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal ();
       }


       public string[] GetSortingLayerNames ()
       {
           Type internalEditorUtilityType = typeof(InternalEditorUtility);
           PropertyInfo sortingLayersProperty = internalEditorUtilityType.GetProperty ("sortingLayerNames", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
           return (string[])sortingLayersProperty.GetValue (null, new object[0]);
       }

       public int[] GetSortingLayerUniqueIDs ()
       {
           Type internalEditorUtilityType = typeof(InternalEditorUtility);
           PropertyInfo sortingLayerUniqueIDsProperty = internalEditorUtilityType.GetProperty ("sortingLayerUniqueIDs", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
           return (int[])sortingLayerUniqueIDsProperty.GetValue (null, new object[0]);
       }
   }
   ```

After this your render mesh inspector view as this:
[image: Mesh Render Inspector]

3. Combine 2d render system and 3d render system. Handle Z-buffer Z-write and many many other ... I believe this great challenge.Unity should do this work not us.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Ahh I see I can of course just add all the layers I wish to be drawn infront of the player, will need some restructuring of the elements but this should work.

Comment: @Svp extra camera should only set culling mask to one specify layer that you want in front.And other camera should delete this layer in culling mask

Comment: yes but once I decide to show the player infront of the stones, that now means player is shown infront of everything because the depth of the camera is higher. which now means I need to put all other objects in that camera as well. after a while I have tons of layers in the "front" camera and it gets mega confusing. And yes for every layer I add to the front one I remove it from the back. things just start getting wonky.

Comment: Could uou do it Reverse. Put less thing to back render.@Svp

Comment: It seems your design  that sometime A render front sometime A render back.So you change layer at runtime.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177574/discussion-between-svp-and-ron-tang).